# Informatica to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, informatica

I have the following informatica coding, however, I am having difficulties transforming it into equivalent SQL coding. I hoped that someone may be able to provide some assistance.

The informatica coding is as follows:

```
'CLASS'||'|'||in_inputfile_name||'|'||REPLACECHR(0, in_cust_number, 'Z' , '' )||'|'||in_order_number
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server uses `+` for string concatenation.  But, you have to cast numbers and dates to the right format.  So, I am guessing something like:

```
'CLASS' + '|' + in_inputfile_name + '|' + REPLACE(in_cust_number, 'Z' , '' ) + '|' + CAST(in_order_number as varchar(255))
```

Just a note about case sensitivity.  `REPLACECHAR()` with an argument of 0 is case sensitive.  SQL Server doesn't have anything quite so easy.  So, if you need case sensitivity, you can use `COLLATE`.  Or, if that is important, then perhaps the database and tables already have a default case-sensitive collation collation.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have yet to check whether the case sensitivity is an issue, but the transformation seems to be working correctly!